# How to best Implement a Google CSE for a WordPress Blog

Tags: wordpress, custom-search-provider

What is the best way to implement a Google Custom Search on a wordpress blog. a plugin or just the normal way? do we still use the search.php in the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of answers: [google cse wordpress - Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=google+cse+wordpress&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)